# PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class) returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, event-handling, rcp, e4

Recently we upgraded our rcp application to e4. We are using Mars. I am trying out e4 event bus. I added `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class);` to a dialog class code. However, this is returning null. I read IEventBroker is intrinsic part of e4 platform. What might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `PlatformUI` in a pure e4 application (or anything else in `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` plugins).

You should inject `IEventBroker` or get it from an `IEclipseContext`.

Note that injection is not done in dialogs if you create them the normal way. You can use `ContextInjectionFactory.make` to create a class with injection.